# runs in R but not Rscript

Tags: r, inline, rcpp

Here is my script

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

myroot2 <- rcpp(signature(xs="numeric"), body='double x=as<double>(xs); return wrap(::sqrt(x));')
print(myroot2(100))
```

If I source this script from R it runs just fine

```
>source('test.R')
Attaching package: ‘inline’

The following object is masked from ‘package:Rcpp’:

registerPlugin

[1] 10
```

In batch mode

```
Rscript --verbose test.R
running
'/usr/local/share/bcbio/anaconda/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore -- 
file=test.R'


Attaching package: ‘inline’

The following object is masked from ‘package:Rcpp’:

registerPlugin
Error in signature(xs = "numeric") : could not find function 
"signature"
Calls: rcpp -> cxxfunction
Execution halted
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `signature` function is in `methods`, which apparently is not loaded by default with `Rscript`. Try this:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

myroot2 <- rcpp(methods::signature(xs="numeric"), body='double x=as<double>(xs); return wrap(::sqrt(x));')
print(myroot2(100))
```

where the only change was to use `methods::signature`.

Comment: It is loaded in R version 3.5.0 and later though.  That change was loooooong overdue.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, good catch on the dupe, I hadn't seen that yet.

Comment: Oh, every second question about `Rscript` is about this :)